# JavaScript images deck shuffle through z-index

Tags: javascript, image, loops, animation, z-index

I have images stacked over each other like a deck of cards, and each one has their z-Index changed in sequence through the code below, so that the final result is an animation. However, it is linear and it doesn't reverse the order, and I would like it to animate both forward and backward. I don't want code, but I do want ideas of what can be done. I'll eventually come up with the code =)

---

```
var imageArray = [];

function placeImage(x) {
    var div = document.getElementById("div_picture");
    div.innerHTML = ""; // clear images

for (counter=1;counter<=x;counter++) {
    var image=document.createElement("img");
    image.src="bola/bola"+counter+".png";
    image.width="500";
    image.height="500";
    image.alt="bola"+counter;
    image.id="imagem"+counter;
    image.style.backgroundColor="rgb(255,255,255)"
    image.style.position="absolute";
    image.style.zIndex=counter;
    div.appendChild(image);
    imageArray[counter-1] = document.getElementById("imagem"+counter);
    }
};

var imageShuffle = function(x) {
    imageArray[x-1].style.zIndex=0;
    for (counter=0;counter<x;counter++) {
        imageArray[counter].style.zIndex++;
    }
    imageArray.splice(0, 0, imageArray[x-1]);
    imageArray.pop();
};

window.onload = function() {
    placeImage(14);
    document.getElementById("div_picture").onclick=function() {setInterval("imageShuffle(14)",1000/14)};
};
```

Comment: follow jQuery UI's lead and stop using `zIndex` to manipulate stacking order.  Give all of your divs a common parent (if they haven't already) and rely on the DOM to stack the elements for you.  Within any common "stacking group" elements will stack in DOM order, so you can use DOM manipulation to re-arrange the order of siblings to change their stacking order.

Comment: @Alnitak Do you have do you use `poistion:absolute` for this?

Comment: @raam86 most likely, yes.

Comment: Ok, but is it bad practice to use pure JavaScript like I did? This is for a JavaScript project, I'm afraid using jQuery would be against the rules set by the teacher. But thanks!

EDIT: Because I don't want to spam. This an answer for the comment below. I get it now, I will proceed to study that method and try to make it! Thanks again!

Comment: I never said to use jQuery, I just suggested following what jQuery did.  They _used_ to use zIndex, but it causes horrible problems for compositing.  In jQuery UI 1.10 they switched to the method I described above.  With their draggable elements whichever element you click on is moved to become the last sibling, so it automatically appears topmost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep pointers to the images in an array in order to use `Array.prototype.sort` MDN
This way you you will have an array of images in any order which you can then manipulate.

```
 imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); //In case you don't have the pics.
 //First we create function to sort by zIndex

function sortZ(a, b) {
    //Make sure z-index is defined if not set to zero
    var b = b.getAttribute('z-index') ? b.getAttribute('z-index') : 0;
    var a = a.getAttribute('z-index') ? a.getAttribute('z-index') : 0;
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function convertDomObject(domObject) {
    var domArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < domObject.length; i++) {
        domArr.push(domObject[i]);
    }
    return domArr;
}
var imgsArr = convertDomObject(imgs); //Use it !
imgsArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return sortZ(b, a)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That's an idea, though I prefer not to look at code. I can't vote up because I lack the "reputation" necessary xD

Comment: If you like the answer you mark it as chosen by clicking the tick under the vote count.